# D-Bus: is there such a thing as a "D-Bus sniffer"?

Tags: linux, monitor, dbus

Is there such a thing as a "D-Bus sniffer" ?

I would like to "sniff" all (or part) of the messages transiting on D-Bus.

Comment: This is one of those candidates for closing because "this doesnt have a real answer". I'm glad the mods haven't found it yet.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

The Ubuntu `dbus` package includes a program named [`dbus-monitor`](http://dbus.freedesktop.org/doc/dbus-monitor.1.html) which seems to do what you want.

Comment: Thanks!  I was googling "sniffer" , "analyzer", "manager"... didn't though about "monitor".

Comment: For those getting the warning, here's how you can automatically set `DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS`: `export $(dbus-launch)`.

Answer (score 15):

If you are looking for a gui with execution possibility try [D-Feet](https://fedorahosted.org/d-feet/)

Answer (score 11):

Bustle ( http://willthompson.co.uk/bustle/ ) will help you visualise the flow of messages over the bus. This uses the same basic mechanism as dbus-monitor to monitor the traffic.

From the website:

"Bustle draws sequence diagrams of D-Bus activity, showing signal emissions, method calls and their corresponding returns, with timestamps for each individual event and the duration of each method call. This can help you check for unwanted D-Bus traffic, and pinpoint why your D-Bus-based application isn't performing as well as you like. It also provides statistics like signal frequencies and average method call times."

Answer (score 3):

Qt has a graphical D-Bus browser called [qdbusviewer](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdbusviewer.html).